# Accessing Wamp Using a wireless router

Tags: java, php, android, wampserver

I am currently using USB tethering to connect My PC to the internet and access wamp Server (App Development). That is working perfectly, but as soon as I try to do the same with a wireless router using a different ip, I get no response from the app.

The following were some of the attempts at debugging this problem....

- I have changed the ip on my java file to that of the wireless router and I still don't get a response.
- I have tried to create a rule for Port 80 to access the sever it's not working as well.
- I have changed the httpd-conf file to Require all granted in all related areas its still not working.
- I have tried changing the Listen statement to the routers ip and still no response.
- I've also checked the Vhost file and changed it to all granted as well but that only gave me permission for the phone that i am tethering on.

I've also noticed that when I tether with a different phone it works only on that phone and nowhere else.

Comment: It is so unclear what you have and what you want. Is it relevant for the things you want that you have something different going?

Comment: Are you talking about a linux server running on an android phone?

Comment: @ greenapps......Not that....Scratch off Linux for now. This is mainly windows. My main issue is trying to connect different mobile

Comment: @ greenapps apologies for being so unclear.....Scratch off Linux for now. This is mainly windows. My main issue is trying to connect different mobile devices using my App to my server in Windows....I am having a bit of trouble connecting my wamp Server to a WiFi ip to enable that ability

Comment: You should really try to explain what you want. Maybe it's something very simple... but all this talking of you...

Comment: Is all that you want exchanging some data between your app on an Android device with a WAMP server on your PC? Both devices in the same WLAN?

Comment: Okay.....I've build an app. I'm am using wamp-server to get data from my laptop and display it on my phone. My challenge is how to allow different devices making use of my app to access this data off this wamp Server on my lapto.

Comment: Yes exactly that.....

Comment: If one app on an android device can connect then all apps on other devices in the same WLAN can also connect. I dont understand why you talk about different devices hence.

Comment: And what is the problem? An android client app should use the ip of the computer where your server is running on. Thats all. Not the ip of the used router.

Comment: Thanx for the continouse reply. here's what I did. On android studio i used the IPv4 adress listed on my computer.(at that point I was connecting to the internet using my phone.....USB Tethering). The IPv4 adress changed when i used a different method to connect to the internet(making use of a WiFi router). So since the ipv4 adress changed on the laptop, I used that one to try and connect instead.

Comment: And... tell the whole story.. you used the ip of the pc.. and...?

Comment: When I used this new IP adress(from the wifi router), I got no response from the app. But when i used the current IP adress (The one using USB tethering) it worked but only for that mobile device that was giving internet to my laptop. If I tested the app on another device which did not directly give the laptop internet. I would get no response

Comment: @ greenapps thanx for the help you were correct I was using 2 different Networks inorder to connect to the server. I was able to achieve my goal by connecting my android device to the wireless router. I was trying to access my laptop without connecting to the router as I thought I only needed to just give the laptop internet and not connect to the same network it was using.